# Is there a JQuery(mobile plugin) for Eclipse?

Tags: jquery, eclipse, jquery-plugins, eclipse-plugin

Is there a JQuery mobile plugin for Eclipse or can you recommend me something similar for Eclipse?  (auto-completion is very important for me.)

Comment: What do you mean jQuery mobile plugin for eclipse? I am assuming you are building for Android. Are you just looking for a good autocomplete plugin that can be used on an Android app using the jQuery mobile framework?

Comment: yeah i am looking for a jquery mobile plugin with autocompletion!(btw if you know a good jquery plugin for eclipse pls recommend it too ;) )

Comment: Eclispe is just a development tool / text editor. There aren't jQuery plugins made for eclipse specifically. Anyways, from what I have heard. The jQuery UI autocomplete should work with mobile. http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: so if i implement a jquery plugin in eclipse that also wouls work with autocompletion?

Comment: btw what I mean by autocompletion is autocompletion for code in eclipse!

Comment: Aha... I thought you were talking about autocomplete for an input field inside of an app.. So are you referring to like "self closing tags" and remembrance of "variables" and "classes"?

Comment: He is looking for code completion for jQuery and jQuery Mobile within eclipse.

Comment: YES ;) do you have a recommentation for me?

Comment: http://www.davincisdk.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSDT plugin may be useful to include jquery in eclipse and it could be found  at this link

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jsdt-jquery#.UI-dH5F62So

Answer (score 1):

this might be what you are looking for..check this out http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/announce-1/mds11eclipsepluginforphonegaponandroidreleasestoday-jquerymobileandsenchatouchadded